# Best way to handle loading of many components with API requests in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, frontend

I'm currently building an SPA in React that fetches around 1000 items of data from some API and shows it in a large list on the main page of the application.

The API has a single end point to fetch all the end points that looks something like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    url: https://api/1
},
{
    id: 2,
    url: https://api/2
}
...
```

In my app I fetch this data in a parent component, map over the resulting array, and render a component for each one. In each said child component I am then calling the end point in the 'url' property to fetch the data needed for that list item.

Obviously this means doing around 1000 API requests simultaneously, which is definitely not ideal. I am trying to work out the most efficient way of rendering the list item components on the page without an enormous detriment to performance.

I have looked in to lazy loading but I can't seem to make it work when rendering components with API requests. I would like to avoid pagination if possible.

Comment: Seems like infinite scroll is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send a request for each item separably in the first place. What you could do is send an array of ids you need and then fetch all data for them in one request. When that's done you render your components, if performance is crucial you can use something called virtualization to improve rendering

If you really want to have best performance I would recommend doing lazy loading with the same principle, for example 50 items per request, when you scroll down to the bottom you load 50 more and so on. Combining this with virtualization you will get very good results

Check this out for vritualization in react:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

There are also a lot of other libraries

Comment: Or `react-window` if this is a simple list, this is the newest lib from bvaughn and is more modern / easier

Comment: It's a third party API that I'm using and the format I described is how the data is retrieved, I don't see any way I can grab 50 items in one request?

Comment: You do the first request, then pass the needed information needed for the individual request to the children (like url, id, etc), which do the request only when they are rendered, in `componentDidMount` or equivalent react hook.

Comment: "_then fetch all data in one request."_ - can't agree with that

Comment: @Tehloltractor in that case you need to stick to client-side optimizations which would be rendering only what you see in the viewport + a buffer zone for instance if you fit 10 of those items on the screen you want to have 15-to 20 ready so you don't see blinking when requests are slow. Then as you scroll you fetch the new data for the coming items

Comment: @kinduser it all depends how data heavy those items are and if always going to be say 1000 items I explained a better approach under that sentance